# How to apply multiple function to data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I tried to do this:

```
DT <- data.table(Monthname = month.name, id = 1:3, a = abs(rnorm(12)), b = abs(rnorm(12)), c = abs(rnorm(12)), d = abs(rnorm(12)))
setkey(DT, id)
ANS <- DT[,lapply(.SD, mean)/lapply(.SD, sd), by = 'id', .SDcols = names(DT)[-1]]
```

but it gives error. So, Are there any ways to do this ? Thank You.

Comment: An alternative to the answer below is to define a function like `myfun <- function(x) mean(x)/sd(x)` and then use `DT[, lapply(.SD, myfun), by = "id", .SDcols = names(DT)[-1]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just that same as one would use `lapply` in other contexts:

```
ANS <- DT[,lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x)/sd(x) ), by = 'id', .SDcols = names(DT)[-1]]
```